# NodeJS: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, heap-memory, exceljs

I'm trying to export data from a file and add this data to an Excel file using ExcelJS.

```
worksheet.addRows(freedomRawData.records);
```

'records' is an array that contains more than 165,000 elements in it. While writing the data to excel file, I get the error -

> FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

The same script works for data with 'record' length 115,000 elements. Over the internet, I found the below method:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 <file_name>.js
```

This didn't work and I tried using the maximum capacity of my RAM (16384MB); which didn't help as well. I'm a newbie in NodeJS, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the goal just to write the spreadsheet out to disk? If so read the [streaming section](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#streaming-io) of the docco. Writing/commiting to the stream then doesn't build the whole spread sheet in memory first

Comment: Yes, the goal is to create a new file post performing certain calculations on the data. Thanks for the above link; I'll read through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExcelJS has a streaming writer interface:

```
async function writeExcel(rows_array){
  const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({ filename: 'stream.xlsx' })
  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('data')
  for (const row of rows_array) {
    worksheet.addRow(row).commit()
  }
  await workbook.commit()
}
```

In this case, the data set could still present a memory problem due to the way the node/v8 garbage collector works. Garbage collection requires a tick of the event loop to actually clean up "freed" memory. If you run enough synchronous code, like a `for` loop, and that loop allocates more memory each iteration, then the GC can't run until after a pause in the code (i.e the final `worbook.commit()`. If you still run into OOM issues then you can force an async pause to allow the row memory that can be cleaned up after a `.commit()` to actually be collected.

```
  for (const i in rows_array) {
    worksheet.addRow(rows_array[i]).commit()
    if (i % 10000 === 0) await Promise.resolve(true)
  }
```

Comment: Worked so well. Thanks, @Matt. I wondered why it didn't work in the first go; until I realized there was a typo in the first Answer `await workbook.commit()` :)